# How to create a classic ska sound?

Tags: mixing, recording, garageband

I've been recording reggae/ska in GarageBand, using a combination of:

- Voice through a condenser mic
- Electric guitar and bass using GarageBand's own amp simulators and effects
- Drum patterns programmed using GarageBand's kits
- Software organ

I play all the parts live, and avoid quantising.

It sounds OK, but a bit sterile. Listening to classic ska tracks that influence me (say, anything from the Trojan Ska boxed set) what seems to characterise the sound most is a benign fuzziness, presumably distortion that engineers tried and failed to avoid using what equipment a 1960s Jamaican studio could afford.

Question one is: how can I replicate that sound using the equipment I have

Question two is: how can I achieve that *feel* without going so extremely lo-fi.

Comment: You use programmed drum patterns and then ask about _feel_?

Comment: Drums are a whole 'nother problem; but let's put them aside for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the vintage feel of those old records is in (1) the kind of mastering that was done for cheaply produced vinyl records, and (2) the wear-and-tear that they have sustained over the years.  Even if you have only heard "remastered" digital versions, if the original was on a fly-by-night Caribbean indy it may have been remastered from the best available vinyl rather than the master tapes.

Mastering for vinyl rolled off a lot of low frequencies and compressed/limited the dynamic range. Age and multiple plays of a record start rolling off the highs and adding noise.

So a mix buss comp/limiter, roll off lows below 100 Hz (experiment), highs above 5k (experiment), and add a "vinyl noise crackle" plugin if you feel like it.  It ain't "vibe in a bottle" but it might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I hear some fuzzy resonance on the higher horns and vocals. My synaesthetic side wants to say it "blooms", like a bloom filter on a photograph. Any idea where that comes from / how to replicate?

Comment: tubes and tape.

Answer (score 0):

Garage Band has a couple of Fuzz Pedals.  They're intended to be used as guitar effects, but you might be able to tweak them to get the sound you're after.

Comment: A Fuzz Pedal is a particular type of extreme distortion, usually used as a guitar effect.  Not likely to be useful to apply to an overall mix in this context.